# Scatter plot with multiple X/Y pairs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to use scatter plot in Google Sheets where multiple X/Y pairs are used as data points. In Microsoft Excel or Libreoffice it is easy to add a series and define its own X and Y axis. However, it seems that in Google sheets, only one column is used as x-axis which make things complicated. So, to plot these two data series:

[image]

I have to move X2 column as an extension to X1 and the move Y2 in a separate column, like this

[image]

For large series, this becomes error prone. Is there a better way to achieve that and preserve the data similar to the first figure?

Comment: Looks like this is the only approach [Google sheets scatter plot multiple series with examples](https://sheetsiq.com/google-sheets/charts/google-sheets-scatter-plot-multiple-series/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula to generate a table in a separate sheet with the layout required as input for the scatter plot and use this as the input range for the chart whilst keeping the source data in its original layout:

```
=arrayformula(let(
headers,A1:E1,
data,A2:E6,
rearranged,split(tocol(split(byrow(headers&"|"&data,lambda(each,join("~",each))),"~|~",FALSE,TRUE)),"|~"),
query(rearranged,"select Col2,max(Col4) group by Col2 pivot Col3 label Col2 'x'",0)))
```

N.B. *headers* corresponds to the row vector containing the series names (in your example A1:E1) and *data* corresponds to the matrix of X & Y values beneath (in your example A2:E6). I am assuming that you will persist with an empty column left between each X/Y pair (e.g. column C in your example). We are using string manipulation to make a flat table from your input data, then QUERY to pivot the data by the series names. Do not use tildes ('~') or pipes ('|') in your series names or you will break the string manipulations used to rearrange the data.